# Python TKInter: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_image'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a Tkinter GUI and I get an attribute error when trying to put a gif image on the canvas.

```
canvas_1 = Canvas(width = 800, height = 450, bg = "blue").pack()
gif = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\Luke\\Desktop\\fb.gif")
canvas_1.create_image(0, 0, image = gif, anchor = NW)
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
  canvas_1.create_image(0, 0, image = gif, anchor = NW)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_image'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In `Tkinter`, the methods `.pack` and `.grid` return `None`.  They don't return the `Widget`.

The fix is simple.  Split it into 2 lines:

```
canvas_1 = Canvas(width = 800, height = 450, bg = "blue")
canvas_1.pack()
```

Comment: thansks, new it would be something simple